# Scraping Data with Python and LXML

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I am facing some difficulty in scraping data with lxml.

The code snippet is:

```
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
f = open("test1.html", "r")
content = f.read()
tree   = etree.fromstring(content, parser)
print tree.xpath('//table[@id="table_search_results"]/tbody/tr')
```

And my html snippet is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class=" gecko ff3 linux js gecko ff3 linux js">
 ............
 ............

 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="100" id="table_search_results"><tbody><tr></tr></tbody></table> </html>
```

But I am unable to get the table data from my python code. The print statement is showing null, whereas clearly I have the table element with the given id.

Please help.

Comment: It works for me for the sample data you've provided. I see `[<Element tr at 0x10d6d59e0>]` printed.